# grepping patterns and deleting files

Tags: file, grep

I have an external file that contains a list of patterns (pattern per line).

```
pattern1
foo bar
pattern_n
bar
bar foo
```

I would like to `grep` all files including the ones within sub-folders using those patterns, if the pattern matches, copy the file to some /tmp/mybackup/ and then delete it. What would be a good way of doing this?

Comment: Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: Sure, basically go over all the files in the current dir (including subfolders) and `grep` lines containing a match to the given PATTERN (from the list file) if the pattern is found backup the file where it was found and delete it from the current folder.

Comment: "copy and then delete". Why not just *move* the file?

Comment: @thkala: you are completely right! that will work too

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you're satisfied, please select the answer you think is best (presumably Eelvex') as the accepted answer; this will make it more likely that people will respond to your future questions. :-)

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need the following switches to grep:

- `-R` to scan recursively
- `-l` to print only matching filenames
- `-f` to read the patterns from a file
- `-I` to ignore binary files

so:

```
grep -RlIf patterns-file *
```

then feed this result to some other utility to perform the backup, eg xargs:

```
grep -RlIf patterns-file * | xargs -I {} mv {} /tmp/backup
```

or with a loop:

```
for afile in `grep -RlIf patterns-file *`; do
   mv $afile /tmp/backup
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for x in `fgrep -f patternfile.txt -l -r .`; do cp $x /tmp/mybackup; rm $x; done
```

Comment: Use Eelvex' answer instead of mine, since he uses xargs and explains what the switches does (I don't have enough reputation to upvote or to add comments to someone else's reply) - and also since I didn't (either) realize that cp + rm == mv ;-)

Comment: @Eelvex: Thanks - upvoting your answer. :-) (Grammar self-correction: "what the switches _do_".)